# How to use java multi-threading properly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I many examples in Internet there are almost all the same:

```
public class Test extends Thread {
    public synchronized void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("i::"+i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(obj);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

So why would I call same task (in run() method) three times with different threads? E.g. if I want to upload a file, then why would I call it three times?
I assume if I need multithreading then:

```
thread t1 would do task1, e.g.:
   - update database info
thread t2 would do task2, e.g.:
   - upload file to server
thread t3 would do task3, e.g.:
   - bring a message to an user
```

Is there an example that would to work like that described above.

Comment: It is just an example of how to create multiple threads - no one says it is a solution to some specific scenario. "_Is there an example that would to work like that described above._" Just make different objects - you don't have to make `Test` and use it over and over.

Comment: so as I understand there should be three different "public class Test1 extends Thread, public class Test2 extends Thread, public class Test3 extends Thread, ..." ?

Comment: Yes and then you can do whatever you want in each one of those.

Comment: For the record, this implementation is pointless because `run()` is synchronized, which means only one thread can execute it at a time.

Comment: I just thought there is an real example to understand whether it's worth to use multithreading. As in my original example - it's clear to understand multithreading but I don't see any sense to use it. So does anyone have an example when e.g. thread1 reads a file, thread2 do some calculation, then whoever done first notifies the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple threads the code given below where you only start thread and you don't need to call multiple times a same method. As you can see, once it started, all three child threads share the CPU. Notice the call to sleep(10000) in main( ). This causes the main thread to sleep for ten seconds and ensures that it will finish last.

```
     // Create multiple threads.
         class NewThread implements Runnable
            { 
                String name;
            } // name of thread Thread t;
              NewThread(String threadname) 
              { 
                  name = threadname;
              } 
              t = new Thread(this, name); 
              System.out.println("New thread: " + t); 
              t.start(); // Start the thread 
        }
    // This is the entry point for thread.
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            { 
                for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    System.out.println(name + ": " + i); 
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                System.out.println(name + "Interrupted");
            } 
            System.out.println(name + " exiting."); 
        }
    }
    class MultiThreadDemo 
    { 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            new NewThread("One"); // start threads
            new NewThread("Two"); 
            new NewThread("Three");
        try 
        { 
            // wait for other threads to end
            Thread.sleep(10000); 
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted"); 
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
        }
        }
```

Reference from **The Complete Reference By Herbert Schildt**